# Docker: standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: linux, docker, build

I have created one docker multiarch image with buildx command.

```
sudo docker buildx build -f build/Dockerfile --platform linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/amd64 -t uditgaurav/chaos-operator:v3 . --push
```

build/Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.13 

ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=1 

ENV OPERATOR=/usr/local/bin/chaos-operator \
    USER_UID=1001 \
    USER_NAME=chaos-operator

# install operator binary
COPY build/_output/bin/chaos-operator ${OPERATOR}

COPY build/bin /usr/local/bin

RUN  /usr/local/bin/user_setup

RUN export GOOS=$(echo ${TARGETPLATFORM} | cut -d / -f1) && \
    export GOARCH=$(echo ${TARGETPLATFORM} | cut -d / -f2) && \
    GOARM=$(echo ${TARGETPLATFORM} | cut -d / -f3 | cut -c2-)

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint"]

USER ${USER_UID}
```

**In [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/uditgaurav/chaos-operator/tags) the images came with diff [arch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9V40.png)**:

But when I ran it in arm clusters it is showing error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Docker Version on ARM cluster

```
Client:
 Version:           19.03.6
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        369ce74a3c
 Built:             Fri Feb 28 23:47:53 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/arm64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.6
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       369ce74a3c
  Built:            Wed Feb 19 01:06:16 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.3.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.2
  GitCommit:        
 runc:
  Version:          spec: 1.0.1-dev
  GitCommit:        
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:
```

can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker multiarch build is not the problem. The problem is that `/usr/local/bin/chaos-operator` is an linux/amd64 binary and you're trying to run it on linux/arm64.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error while trying to build an image on ARM664. Could you please help me?

Comment: I'm guessing your somewhere during your build you're trying to run an executable not compiled for that architecture.

Comment: You won't get any help on SO by asking for it in a comment to an answer to another question, even if it is tangentially related. If you want assistance, ask a separate question and put your Dockerfile, description of the issue and any other relevant information in it.